# Only execute MySQL stored procedure if it hasn't already ran today

Tags: mysql, sql

This is mostly an insurance type of addition to an already working stored procedure, I just can't seem to get the code to work.

I declared `dt` and had an `if` statement that was checking if `dt = date(now())` but I'm doing something wrong as this throws an error. I'm open to more efficient/smarter ways to check for this as well. This is just what I came up with.

```
--/
CREATE PROCEDURE Matt.find_newwinners()
begin
    declare done int default false;
    declare a varchar(10);

    declare dt varchar(30);
    set dt = (select date(max(dateadded)) from dbo.newwins);

    declare cur1 cursor for select personoid from dbo.view_newwinners;
    declare continue handler for not found set done = true;

    open cur1;

    read_loop: loop
        fetch cur1 into a;

        if done then leave read_loop;
        end if;

        if dt = date(now()) then leave read_loop;
        /* would also be nice to print a reason why we are exiting */
        end if;

        insert ignore into dbo.newwins (personoid, dateadded) values (a, now());

    end loop;
    close cur1;
end

/
```

Error message:

```
[Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare cur1 cursor for select personoid from dbo.view_newwinners;
declare conti' at line 7
Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000 --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'declare cur1 cursor for select personoid from dbo.view_newwinners;
declare conti' at line 7
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL, not SQL-Server? `dbo` is the default schema in SQL-Server.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. We use a replicated version of a SQL Server database to do our analytical work. They don't like our grubby hands in their source tables ;)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: It isn't very explanatory, but I have placed the error message into the body of the question.

Comment: @MatthewSnell . . . You are doing *analytic* work on MySQL in preference to SQL Server.  Let me just say, that wouldn't be my choice.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree completely. We are pushing for our own instance of SQL Server but I am not at the pay grade to make that decision happen.

Comment: The error messages are because cursors can't be declared at that place in the procedure. But see my answer, you don't need cursors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you're getting have nothing to do with the `IF` statement, they're because cursors have to be declared right after the `BEGIN` statement. See [syntax error on DECLARE CURSOR FOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423310/syntax-error-on-declare-cursor-for).

However, your procedure can be simplified so you don't need the cursors at all. Just use an `INSERT ... SELECT` to insert the results of a query into a table, and put the `IF` around the query.

```
--/
CREATE PROCEDURE Matt.find_newwinners()
begin

    declare dt DATE;
    set dt = (select date(max(dateadded)) from dbo.newwins);
    IF dt != TODAY() THEN 
        INSERT INTO dbo.newwins (personoid, dateadded)
        SELECT personoid, NOW()
        FROM dbo.view_newwinners;
    END IF

end

/
```

You can even get rid of the `IF` entirely:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.newwins (personoid, dateadded)
SELECT personoid, NOW()
FROM dbo.view_newwinners
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DATE(MAX(dateadded)) AS lastadded
    FROM dbo.newwins) AS x
WHERE lastadded != TODAY();
```